# Normalization of corpus to find perplexity

Tags: normalization, natural-language, entropy, information-theory, perplexity

In the formula of finding the perplexity of a corpus, why is it normalized based on the total number of words?

Why shouldn't be normalized based on number of sentences? If # of sentences is used for normalization, is it valid computation?

Perplexity(C)=N-th root of 1/P(S1,S2..Sn) where N = number of words in the corpus

---- reference:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143638/287956

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated SE. Could you add the formula of finding the perplexity of a corpus to your question which you have mentioned

Comment: @Pluviophile Thank you a response. Added the formula

Comment: This might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/perplexity-in-language-models-87a196019a94