# Finding the perplexity of multiple examples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, language-models, perplexity

I am trying to find a way to calculate perplexity of a language model of multiple 3-word examples from my test set, or perplexity of the corpus of the test set. As the test set, I have a paragraph which I've split into 3-word examples like this:
if the corpus is "Hello my name is Jack.", my 3-word examples would be "Hello my name", "my name is" and "name is Jack". The first 2 words are fed into the language model and the third is the correct label.

I've tried to compile a function which would calculate perplexities from the following links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697318/how-to-implement-perplexity-in-keras

- here I've chosen this function to calculate perplexity of individual examples

```py
from keras import backend as K
def perplexity(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    The perplexity metric. Why isn't this part of Keras yet?!
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881308/how-to-calculate-perplexity-of-rnn-in-tensorflow
    https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8267
    """
    #cross_entropy = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    cross_entropy = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    perplexity = K.exp(cross_entropy)
    return perplexity
```

- my labels are one-hot and I've found somewhere that for one-hot labels, `categorical_crossentropy` should be used instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. This function seems to work fine for individual examples (weird examples get higher perplexity, while normal examples get lower).

According to this question I've tried to compile a function for final perplexity, which would give me only one number instead of a number for each individual example: [How to find the perplexity of a corpus](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129352/how-to-find-the-perplexity-of-a-corpus)

This is the code I've come up with:

```py
def total_perplexity(perplexities, N):
    # Perplexities is tf.Tensor
    # N is vocab size
    log_perp = K.log(perplexities)
    sum_perp = K.sum(log_perp)
    divided_perp = sum_perp / N
    return np.exp(-1 * sum_perp)
```

- here `perplexities` is the outcome of `perplexity(y_true, y_pred)` function. However, for different examples - some of which make sense and some of which are total gibberish, the final perplexity tends to get towards 1 for smaller texts and tends to go to 0 as the size of the corpus grows.

What am I doing wrong?

Alternatively, do you recommend any other metrics for evaluating my language model?

**EDIT:** I've tried also a different approach, taking the true label's prediction probability (model.predict(...)) as the word's probability and putting that into the formula for implementing the corpus perplexity. Here is the new function:

```py
def final_perplexity(y_true, y_pred, vocab_size):
    # Perplexities is tf.Tensor
    # N is vocab size
    one_hot_indices = [np.where(r==1)[0][0] for r in y_true]
    one_hot_probabilities = y_pred[range(len(one_hot_indices)),one_hot_indices]
    log_perp = K.log(one_hot_probabilities)
    divided_perp = log_perp / vocab_size
    sum_perp = K.sum(divided_perp)
    return np.exp(-1 * sum_perp)
```

Now the perplexity goes into infinity for larger corpus. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm you take is probably for the wrong basis. The log-exp-trick relies on 'changing nothing' in a mathematical meaning. For example:

$$
\Leftrightarrow
\log_{10}(10^4) = 4 \\
10^{log_{10}(10^4)} = 10000
$$

But this only works with the right base:
$$a^{log_{a}(b)} = b$$

If you take 2 to the power of something your logarithm should be with respect to the basis of 2. However, my guess is that the `log` function of Keras is taking the natural logarithm (with basis of Euler's number instead).

To get the logarithm of base 2 you could do something like that:

```
def log2(x):
    return K.log(x) / K.log(2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've taken it into account. It helps a little, but I'm not sure it entirely fixes the problem :)